# How to detect whether the Mouse Hovers above a drawn line in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, hover, line, mouse

I have a panel on a form. On this panel there are drawn a few lines. I would like to know how to detect when the Mouse is above one of the lines and get the details of the line.

Comment: You can use the MouseOver event, get the X/Y co-ordinates of the mouse and see if they intersect with the line

Comment: If you draw your shapes using a GraphicsPath, you can use its `IsOutlineVisible([Mouse position], [Pen Size])`and `IsVisible()` methods. In the case of a simple line, you have to use the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Keep track of your lines in a data structure, e.g. an array, as you draw them.
2. Create a handler for the panel's MouseMove event.
3. In the handler, iterate over the (array of) lines and compute the distance from the mouse's position to the nearest point on the line (see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) for the math).
4. If the distance is below a certain threshold, display the information.